# html / css 2 elements always at the same line

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I have a 2 tables in HTML (I am using PrimeFaces UI Framework for Java) where I have 2 button in different table but I want both to be always at the same line.

I add style `margin-top:100px;` to the Button 1 and it is in the correct position now:

[image: correct]

But if appear a input error of the Textbox 1 this happen:

[image: Error]

Div of the button:

```
<div class="mail_sendBtn">
     <h:commandButton class="mail_sendBtn doBlock"
              id="btn_send"
              action="#{preEntryAccountMBean.submit}"
              value="E-mail"
              type="submit"
              onclick = "storeMail()" />
    <p:defaultCommand target="btn_send" />
```

Style of  of the Button 1:

```
input.mail_sendBtn {
    width: 300px;
    height: 59px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-width: 0;
    background-color: #ffa800;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 102px;
}
```

This is the error tr:

```
<tr>
   <td colspan="2">
          <h:message id="mailAddressInputMessage" 
                     for="preEntryMailAddressInput" 
                     class="error_message"/>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You can not easily force such a “connection” between elements that don’t have any _structural_ connection to begin with. Apart from the fact that this should probably rather not be (ab-)using tables in the first place (because it doesn’t sound like you did have actual tabular data to begin with here), I don’t think there’s much of an option besides using JavaScript to “measure” where elements are, and then dynamically updating the margins.  […]

Comment: […] “Magic numbers” hard-coded into your CSS is something you rather want to avoid, because those always have the potential to fail due to any circumstance you did not take into account or have no control over (viewport size, font size, zoom level ...)

Comment: But the mere fact that you _want_ those buttons to be on the same level suggests that they also might have a _logical_ connection, which means this should not be split over two different tables to begin with (if it has to be tables for some reason.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed adding to the error-message style: position:absolute;